# C to Fortran push stack function conversion

Tags: fortran, stack, push

I am attempting to translate c code to fortran language. The code is a push function into stack.  I've got the translation completed and the code is running but I am not getting the desired output.
The c code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 30

char stack[MAX][MAX];
int top = -1;

void push(char str[]){
 if(top != MAX-1){
  strcpy(stack[++top], str);
  printf("test1 : %s\n",stack[top]);
  }
 else{
  printf("Stack overflow : May be invalid prefix expression\n");
 }
}

int main(){

push("abcd");

return 0;
}
```

My translation in Fortran is:

```
 program testf1
 implicit none
 integer   :: maximum
 integer   :: top
 character(len=:), allocatable :: i 
 character, dimension(:), allocatable :: stack  

 maximum = 30
 top = 0


 allocate (stack(maximum))
 i=trim('abcd')
 print*,"this is the test ",i," is ", push(i)

 contains 

 function push(str) result(out1)
 character(len=:), allocatable, intent(in)   :: str ! input
 !character(len=:), allocatable, intent(out)  :: out1 ! output
 character, dimension(:), allocatable        :: out1 ! output
 integer :: length

 length = len(str)
 allocate (out1(length))
 if (top .NE. maximum - 1 ) then
     top=top+1
     out1(top)=str
     print*, "testf1 : ", out1(top)
  else
  print*, "Stack2 overflow : May be invalid prefix expression"
 end if 
 end function push

end program testf1
```

Instead of abcd I am getting a.  I suspect I should use subroutine instead function because push should not return the value like in c language. But I am still struggling with string manipulation. Is my approach correct?  I also think that in c there is an error in variable declaration because there should be char stack[max] or 1 dimension array which I already addressed that in fortran.

Comment: You assign to only one element of the function result array.

Comment: The program design seems rather odd.  The program variable `stack` is not updated, or used in any other way, by the function `push`.  Should it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not do what you want, because when you say

```
out1(top)=str
```

in your code, you are basically assigning the contents of `str` to the last character of `out1`, which, given your input `'abcd'` to the function, yields the character `a`. There are many better ways to achieve what you want and here is one way of doing it in modern Fortran:

```
! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612689/c-to-fortran-push-stack-function-conversion
module Stack_mod

    integer, parameter :: MAX_STACK_SIZE = 30

    type :: JaggedArray_type
        character(:), allocatable :: Record
    end type JaggedArray_type

    type :: Stack_type
        integer :: top = 0
        type(JaggedArray_type) :: Array(MAX_STACK_SIZE)
    contains
        procedure, pass :: push
    end type Stack_type

contains

    subroutine push(Stack,record)
        implicit none
        class(Stack_type), intent(inout)    :: Stack
        character(*), intent(in)            :: record
        if (Stack%top>MAX_STACK_SIZE) then
            write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "Stack2 overflow: May be invalid prefix expression"
        else
            Stack%top = Stack%top + 1
            Stack%Array(Stack%top)%record = record
            write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "this is the test",Stack%top,"is",Stack%Array(Stack%top)%record
        end if 
    end subroutine push

end module Stack_mod

program testf1

    use Stack_mod, only: Stack_type
    implicit none
    type(Stack_type) :: Stack
    call Stack%push("abcd")
    write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "This is from the main program: ", Stack%Array(Stack%top)%record

end program testf1
```

Compiling and running this by a Fortran 2008 compiler, gives:

```
$gfortran -std=f2008 testf1.f90 -o main
$main
this is the test 1 is abcd
This is from the main program:  abcd
```

You can test it here online: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php

I hope I did not simply answer a homework question here and that you are trying to learn something on StackOverflow.

Comment: No. it is not a homework.  I am trying to learn fortran.  I asked myself, there are so many programming languages, which one is good and which one I should concentrate on? Well, it depends on ones perspective and its application. I chose to benchmark them based on computing speed of compiled code.  I know a little bit about pascal, java and c++.  So I wrote routine for each to do looped basic calculations such as add, subtract, sin etc. and compared them.  I did java, octave, c++, c, pascal, fortran,  To my dismay, fortran was the winner, then c++ = C. Now I am trying a c code from web.

Comment: I am just translating c code to fortran for benchmarking purpose as well as to learn basic fortran.

Comment: If performance is important for your work (for example, if you have many many `push` calls in your main code, which results in many many automatic allocations of `record`), then I'd recommend modifying the above code to use a fixed length for `record`.  Memory allocation is costly in any language, including Fortran. Also, if you are new to Fortran, a comprehensive resource for learning and reference is "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf 2018: https://books.google.com/books?id=sB1rDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: For an absolute beginner introduction to modern Fortran (90, but not beyond), this lecture notes has turned out to be a useful resource for my students (I am not the author): https://www.uv.es/dogarcar/man/IntrFortran90.pdf

Comment: Its not work related. It is my learning project.  Eventually it will be related to work in the future I hope. But it is good to develop a good habits at the beginning during the learning process.  Thanks for tips.